# ActiveRecord :has_many and custom foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have the following structure:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_units
    has_many :units, :through => :product_units, :foreign_key => :unitID
end

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_units
    has_many :products, :through => :product_units, :foreign_key => :productID
end

class ProductUnit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :unit, :foreign_key => :unitID
    belongs_to :product, :foreign_key => :productID
end
```

but as I try to run

```
Product.last.units.create({:name => 'test', :symbol => 't'})
```

The following error occurs :

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: product_id
```

Can someone help me ? it's driving me crazy :x

**EDIT:**
When I try the following:

```
Product.last.units
```

I get the error

```
SELECT "units".* FROM "units" INNER JOIN "product_units" ON "units"."unitID" = "product_units"."unitID" WHERE "product_units"."product_id" = 1
```

The problem is that product_units has no product_id field, instead its name is productID; why the identifier name is correct on join but not in the where statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try "productID" instead of :productID? 
It's seem that this problem relate to auto-camelization feature in rails.